# How to use the second parent class methods which is inheriting from an interface in python?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to implement an interface and this interface is taken by two concrete classes say `class First` and `class Second`, I have another class that takes these two classes as a parent `class CO`. The `class CO` makes a decision based on a flag to return which of the two inherited classes, so as to use their implementation.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class common(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def firstfunction(self):
        pass 

    @abstractmethod
    def secondfunction(self):
        pass

class First(common):
    def __init__(self)-> boto3:
        self.ert = "danish"
        # self.username = kwargs["username"]
        # self.password = kwargs["password"]

        print("Inside First function")

    def firstfunction(self):
        print("My implementation of the first function in FIRST CLASS")

    def secondfunction(self):
        print("My implementation of the second function in FIRST CLASS")   

class Second(common):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rty = "pop"
        # self.session_id = kwargs["session_id"]

        print("Inside Second function")

    def firstfunction(self):
        print("My implementation of the first function in SECOND CLASS")

    def secondfunction(self):
        print("My implementation of the second function in SECOND CLASS")

class CO(First, Second):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inst = self.jo()

    def jo(self):
        a = True 

        if a:
            main_object = First()
            return main_object
        else:
            main_object = Second()
```

I am instantiating and calling the methods

```py
mymainclass = co()
objt = mymainclass

objt.firstfunction()
objt.secondfunction()
```

So my condition is if the `flag a = True` in the `CO` class then the Concrete class `First` implementation of the methods should be used and we should get the output like this:

> Inside the First function
>
> My implementation of the first function in FIRST CLASS
>
> My implementation of the second function in FIRST CLASS

If the `flag a = False` in the `CO` class then concrete class `Second` should be used and we should get the output like this:

> Inside the Second function
>
> My implementation of the first function in FIRST CLASS
>
> My implementation of the second function in FIRST CLASS

From the given code I am getting the following output for the flag `a = False` :

> Inside the Second function
>
> My implementation of the first function in FIRST CLASS
>
> My implementation of the second function in FIRST CLASS

Can someone make this code work? What am I doing wrong? I know I can make a function that takes these two classes as variables and then return what I want based on a condition. But I want to use classes for the same

Comment: Hey Danish, could you take some time to polish up the code sample here? I already fixed up the formatting and broken import line, but there's some issues to tidy up. For example, `boto3` doesn't exist, and there's a bunch of random properties, a missing `return` in the `else` branch, and some really random identifier names ("Co"? "jo"?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not inherit class `CO` from either `First` or `Second` because you want to end up with an object that is *either* an instance of class `First` *or* class `Second`. The most straightforward way of doing this is to define method `__new__` which will give you more control over instance creation.

Keep all of your code the same (after fixing the obvious errors, such as `boto3` not being defined) and changing class `CO` as follows:

```py
class CO:
    def __new__(cls):
        a = True

        if a:
            main_object = First()
        else:
            main_object = Second()
        return main_object

o = CO()
print(type(o))
```

Prints:

```None
Inside First function
<class '__main__.First'>
```

**If you want to better parameterize the instance creation (and simplify the code within `__new__`), then have variable `a` be an argument to `CO`:**

```py
class CO:
    def __new__(cls, a):
        return First() if a else Second()

o = CO(False)
print(type(o))
```

Prints:

```None
Inside Second function
<class '__main__.Second'>
```

You could optionally have class `CO` have `common` as its base class to document that instantiating this class results in an instance that implements the `common` interface.  But doing so will not result in enforcing the actual type that is returned by `__new__`:

```py
class CO(common):
    def __new__(cls, a) -> common:
        # The Python interpreter is not type-checking what is returned:
        #return First() if a else Second()
        return []

o = CO(False)
print(type(o))
```

Prints:

```None
<class 'list'>
```

**You can also substitute a factory function for class `CO`:**

```py
def common_factory(a):
    return First() if a else Second()

o = common_factory(False)
```

**Note**

If you want to ensure that classes that inherit from base class `common` must override both `firstfunction` and `secondfunction` to more closely emulate a pure interface as implemented in other object-oriented languages, then you should define these functions in `common` so that they raise an `NotImplementedError` exception:

```py
class common(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def firstfunction(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abstractmethod
    def secondfunction(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Unfortunately, the enforcement is done at run time with its attendant surprises instead of at compile time as is done in other object-oriented languages.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think in this situation, CO class must come from common class and implement the first and second function. In the implementation, it will use the First or Second classes functions depends on the result of jo function. Here is the correct Co class code:

```
class CO(common):

    def __init__(self):
        self.inst = self.jo()

    def jo(self):
        a = False

        if a:
            return First()

        return Second()

    def firstfunction(self):
        self.inst.firstfunction()

    def secondfunction(self):
        self.inst.secondfunction()


a = CO()
a.firstfunction()
a.secondfunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call the method you want by using the class name.

Unless you have some pressing reason to do this that you didn't include in your question, I would avoid this in favor of a factory function that returns either a `First` or `Second` instance depending on the inputs.

```
class common(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def firstfunction(self):
        pass 

    @abstractmethod
    def secondfunction(self):
        pass

class First(common):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ert = "danish"
        super().__init__(self)
    def firstfunction(self):
        print("My implementation of the first function in FIRST CLASS")

    def secondfunction(self):
        print("My implementation of the second function in FIRST CLASS")   

class Second(common):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rty = "pop"
        super().__init__(self)
    def firstfunction(self):
        print("My implementation of the first function in SECOND CLASS")

    def secondfunction(self):
        print("My implementation of the second function in SECOND CLASS")

class CO(First, Second):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
    def use_first(self):
        return True or False  # whatever logic you have for determining this
    def firstfunction(self):
        if self.use_first():
            return First.firstfunction(self)
        else:
            return First.firstfunction(self)
```

Comment: Your code does not match your description of "I would avoid this in favor of a factory function that returns either a First or Second instance depending on the inputs." You are not returning either `First` or a `Second` but rather an instance of `CO`, which inherits from both and *then* deciding to which base class you will be delegating method invocations. See my answer for something that matches your description.

Comment: @Booboo "This" in that sentence refers to the technique that was requested and that I was demonstrating. Maybe there's some reason they need to do things this way, i don't know.